# Spring Integration Java Configuration suddenly fails after upgrade to Spring Framework 4.2.4

Tags: spring-integration

I upgraded our Spring Framework to **4.2.4** from 4.1.4. Our Spring Integration version is at 4.2.0, but the problem will also occur on SI 4.2.4.

After upgrading to SF 4.2.2 we received this runtime error:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@41799345.inboundRouting.inputChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

When I examine the logs, I DO **NOT** see that transformer:inboundRoutingConfig.assignPriority.transformer is added as a subscriber to inboundRouting.inputChannel.  This explains the "Dispatcher has no subscribers".  However, *if I revert back to SF 4.1.4*, I **DO** see the transformer added as a subscriber to the channel and all runs well.

Any ideas why the Spring Framework upgrade is causing this issue?

Here is the particular configuration, and the part that fails is the `assignPriority` @Transformer annotated method.

Please note that `@EnableConfiguration` is located on another `@Configuration` annotated class within the project, but I did also try adding it to this class.

```
@Configuration
public class InboundRoutingConfig {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InboundRoutingConfig.class);

private final static String RESOURCE_AWARE_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL = "inboundRouting.resourceAwareOutputChannel";
private final static String STANDARD_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL = "inboundRouting.standardOutputChannel";
private final static String INBOUND_ROUTING_INPUT_CHANNEL = "inboundRouting.inputChannel";
private final static String ROUTING_CHANNEL = "inboundRouting.outboundRoutingChannel";
private SpringIntegrationHelper SpringIntegrationConfigHelper;
private InboundRoutingMessagePrioritizer inboundRoutingMessagePrioritizer;
private AmqpTemplate resourceAwarePriorityTemplate;
private RouterMapper routerMapper;
private AmqpTemplate standardPriorityTemplate;


@Transformer(inputChannel = INBOUND_ROUTING_INPUT_CHANNEL, outputChannel = ROUTING_CHANNEL, autoStartup="true")
public PriorityMessage assignPriority( PriorityMessage msg, MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
    logger.debug("RECV: InboundRouting content id [{}], request id [{}]", msg.getContentId(), msg.getRequestId());
    return inboundRoutingMessagePrioritizer.setPriorityAndResourceAware(msg, messageHeaders);
}

@Router(inputChannel = ROUTING_CHANNEL, autoStartup="true",
        channelMappings={"true=" + RESOURCE_AWARE_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL, "false=" + STANDARD_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL})
public String resourceAwareRouter(PriorityMessage pm) {
    return Boolean.toString(routerMapper.inboundRoutingIsResourceAware(pm)).toLowerCase();
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel=RESOURCE_AWARE_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
public void inboundRoutingToResourceAwareOutputEndpoint(PriorityMessage pm, MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
    resourceAwarePriorityTemplate.convertAndSend(pm, new CoreAnalysisMessagingService.CopyHeadersPostProcessor(messageHeaders));
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel=STANDARD_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
public void inboundRoutingToStandardOutputEndpoint(PriorityMessage pm,  MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
    standardPriorityTemplate.convertAndSend(pm,  new CoreAnalysisMessagingService.CopyHeadersPostProcessor(messageHeaders));
}



/************************************************************************
 *                                                                      *
 *                        Infrastructure                                *
 *                                                                      *
 ************************************************************************/

@Bean(name = "exec.inboundRouting")
TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor e = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    e.setCorePoolSize(1);
    e.setQueueCapacity(1);
    return e;
}

@Bean(name = "inboundRouting.inboundChannelAdapter")
public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter inboundRoutingInboundChannelAdapter(
        @Qualifier("exec.inboundRouting") TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
        @Qualifier(INBOUND_ROUTING_INPUT_CHANNEL) MessageChannel inputChannel,
        @Qualifier("inboundRoutingQueue") Queue inboundQueue) {

    org.aopalliance.aop.Advice[] adviceChain = new org.aopalliance.aop.Advice[] { };
    int concurrentConsumers = 1;
    AmqpInboundChannelAdapter a = springIntegrationConfigHelper.createInboundChannelAdapter(taskExecutor,
            inputChannel, new Queue[] { inboundQueue }, concurrentConsumers, adviceChain);
    return a;
}

@Bean(name = INBOUND_ROUTING_INPUT_CHANNEL)
public MessageChannel resourceAwareInputChannel() {
    DirectChannel c = new DirectChannel();
    c.setComponentName(INBOUND_ROUTING_INPUT_CHANNEL);
    c.setBeanName(INBOUND_ROUTING_INPUT_CHANNEL);
    return c;
}

@Bean(name = "inboundRouting.outboundRoutingChannel")
public MessageChannel resourceAwareOutboundRoutingChannel() {
    DirectChannel c = new DirectChannel();
    c.setComponentName(ROUTING_CHANNEL);
    c.setBeanName(ROUTING_CHANNEL);
    return c;
}

@Bean(name = RESOURCE_AWARE_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
public MessageChannel inboundRoutingToResourceAwareOutboundChannel() {
    DirectChannel c = new DirectChannel();
    c.setComponentName(RESOURCE_AWARE_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL);
    c.setBeanName(RESOURCE_AWARE_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL);
    return c;
}

@Bean(name = STANDARD_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
public MessageChannel inboundRoutingToStandardOutboundChannel() {
    DirectChannel c = new DirectChannel();
    c.setComponentName(STANDARD_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL);
    c.setBeanName(STANDARD_OUTBOUND_CHANNEL);
    return c;
}

/************************************************************************
 *                                                                      *
 *               Inbound routing config setters                         *
 *                                                                      *
 ************************************************************************/

@Autowired
public void setInboundRoutingMessagePrioritizer (InboundRoutingMessagePrioritizer inboundRoutingMessagePrioritizer) {
    this.inboundRoutingMessagePrioritizer = inboundRoutingMessagePrioritizer;
}

@Autowired
public void setSpringIntegrationConfigHelper (SpringIntegrationHelper springIntegrationConfigHelper) {
    this.springIntegrationConfigHelper = springIntegrationConfigHelper;   
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("resourceAwarePriorityTemplate")
public void setResourceAwarePriorityTemplate(AmqpTemplate resourceAwarePriorityTemplate) {
    this.resourceAwarePriorityTemplate = resourceAwarePriorityTemplate;
}

@Autowired
public void setRouterMapper(RouterMapper routerMapper) {
    this.routerMapper = routerMapper;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("standardPriorityTemplate")
public void setStandardPriorityTemplate(AmqpTemplate standardPriorityTemplate) {
    this.standardPriorityTemplate = standardPriorityTemplate;
}
}
```

**Here is the stack trace from the error**:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:865)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:760)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1345)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@41799345.inboundRouting.inputChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:153)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    ... 21 more
```

**This is a compressed configuration that duplicates the problem:**

```
@EnableIntegration
@Configuration
public class CompressedConfig {
private final static String INPUT_CHANNEL = "testSpring.inputChannel";
private final static String SERVICE_ACTIVATOR_CHANNEL = "testSpring.service";

private String exchangeName = "amq.direct";
private String queueName = "testSpring";

private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
private MessageConverter messageConverter;

@Bean
public Queue testSprintQueue(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
    boolean durable = true;
    boolean exclusive = false;
    boolean autoDelete = false;

    Exchange exchange = new DirectExchange(exchangeName, durable, autoDelete);
    rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exchange);

    Map<String,Object> arguments = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName,
            durable,
            exclusive,
            autoDelete,
            arguments);

    rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);

    Binding binding = new Binding(queueName,
            DestinationType.QUEUE,
            exchangeName,
            queueName,
            null);
    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);

    return queue;
}

@Bean
public AmqpTemplate testSpringTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setChannelTransacted(false);
    template.setExchange(exchangeName);
    template.setQueue(queueName);
    template.setRoutingKey(queueName);
    template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    return template;
}

@Transformer(inputChannel = INPUT_CHANNEL, outputChannel = SERVICE_ACTIVATOR_CHANNEL)
public String transform( TestMessage msg, MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
    return msg.getContents();
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel=SERVICE_ACTIVATOR_CHANNEL)
public void serviceActivator(String msg, MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
    System.out.println("serviceActivator: " + msg);
}

@Bean(name = "exec.testSpring")
TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor e = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    e.setCorePoolSize(1);
    e.setQueueCapacity(1);
    return e;
}

@Bean(name = "testSpring.inboundChannelAdapter")
public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter inboundRoutingInboundChannelAdapter(
        @Qualifier("exec.testSpring") TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
        @Qualifier(INPUT_CHANNEL) MessageChannel inputChannel,
        @Qualifier("testSprintQueue") Queue queue) {

     int concurrentConsumers = 1;

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer =
            new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    //AUTO is default, but setting it anyhow.
    listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    listenerContainer.setAutoStartup(true);
    listenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
    listenerContainer.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    listenerContainer.setQueues(queue);
    listenerContainer.setPrefetchCount(1);
    listenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    listenerContainer.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);

    AmqpInboundChannelAdapter a = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(listenerContainer);
    a.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    a.setAutoStartup(true);
    a.setOutputChannel(inputChannel);
    return a;


}

@Bean(name = INPUT_CHANNEL)
public MessageChannel inputChannel() {
    DirectChannel c = new DirectChannel();
    c.setComponentName(INPUT_CHANNEL);
    c.setBeanName(INPUT_CHANNEL);
    return c;
}

@Bean(name = SERVICE_ACTIVATOR_CHANNEL)
public MessageChannel serviceChannel() {
    DirectChannel c = new DirectChannel();
    c.setComponentName(SERVICE_ACTIVATOR_CHANNEL);
    c.setBeanName(SERVICE_ACTIVATOR_CHANNEL);
    return c;
}

@Autowired
public void setConnectionFactory (ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
}

@Autowired
public void setMessageConverter(@Qualifier("jsonMessageConverter") MessageConverter messageConverter) {
    this.messageConverter = messageConverter;
}

}

public class TestMessage {

    private String contents;

    public String getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void setContents(String contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }
}
```

**This is what is going on in the helper's `createInboundChannelAdapter()` code:**

```
public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter createInboundChannelAdapter(TaskExecutor taskExecutor
        , MessageChannel outputChannel, Queue[] queues, int concurrentConsumers
        , org.aopalliance.aop.Advice[] adviceChain) {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer =
            new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    listenerContainer.setAutoStartup(true);
    listenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
    listenerContainer.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    listenerContainer.setQueues(queues);
    listenerContainer.setErrorHandler(new MyCustomListenerErrorHandler());
    listenerContainer.setPrefetchCount(1);
    listenerContainer.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    listenerContainer.setDefaultRequeueRejected(true);
    if (adviceChain != null && adviceChain.length > 0) {
        listenerContainer.setAdviceChain(adviceChain);
    }

    AmqpInboundChannelAdapter a = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(listenerContainer);
    a.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    a.setAutoStartup(true);
    a.setHeaderMapper(new MyCustomHeaderMapper());
    a.setOutputChannel(outputChannel);
    return a;
}
```

**This is `DEBUG` level output right before and including the exception that results when running a test using the compressed config:**

```
2016-02-18 16:04:50,337 - DEBUG - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer [exec.testSpring-1] - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-lqiTx-rBl_HWPwn8a5G2XQ=testSpring}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://company@192.168.1.46:5672/,22), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2016-02-18 16:04:51,038 - DEBUG - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer [pool-1-thread-8] - Storing delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-lqiTx-rBl_HWPwn8a5G2XQ=testSpring}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://company@192.168.1.46:5672/,22), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2016-02-18 16:04:51,041 - DEBUG - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer [exec.testSpring-1] - Received message: (Body:'{"contents":"Here is my message"}'MessageProperties [headers={__TypeId__=test.TestMessage}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=amq.direct, receivedRoutingKey=testSpring, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0])
2016-02-18 16:04:51,127 - DEBUG - org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher [exec.testSpring-1] - headerName=[json__TypeId__] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2016-02-18 16:04:51,127 - DEBUG - org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher [exec.testSpring-1] - headerName=[amqp_receivedRoutingKey] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2016-02-18 16:04:51,127 - DEBUG - org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher [exec.testSpring-1] - headerName=[amqp_deliveryMode] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2016-02-18 16:04:51,128 - DEBUG - org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher [exec.testSpring-1] - headerName=[amqp_receivedExchange] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2016-02-18 16:04:51,128 - DEBUG - org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher [exec.testSpring-1] - headerName=[amqp_contentEncoding] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2016-02-18 16:04:51,128 - DEBUG - org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher [exec.testSpring-1] - headerName=[contentType] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2016-02-18 16:04:51,128 - DEBUG - org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher [exec.testSpring-1] - headerName=[amqp_redelivered] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2016-02-18 16:04:51,128 - DEBUG - org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher [exec.testSpring-1] - headerName=[amqp_deliveryTag] WILL be mapped, found in [amqp_appId, amqp_clusterId, amqp_contentEncoding, amqp_contentLength, contentType, amqp_correlationId, amqp_deliveryMode, amqp_deliveryTag, amqp_expiration, amqp_messageCount, amqp_messageId, amqp_receivedExchange, amqp_receivedRoutingKey, amqp_redelivered, amqp_replyTo, amqp_timestamp, amqp_type, amqp_userId, json__TypeId__, json__ContentTypeId__, json__KeyTypeId__, amqp_springReplyCorrelation, amqp_springReplyToStack]
2016-02-18 16:04:51,146 - DEBUG - org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel [exec.testSpring-1] - preSend on channel 'testSpring.inputChannel', message: GenericMessage [payload=test.TestMessage@43784f9a, headers={timestamp=1455840291145, id=217e6fc4-4b99-d5e4-0c0d-3c35771b9e90, json__TypeId__=test.TestMessage, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=testSpring, amqp_deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_consumerQueue=testSpring, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-lqiTx-rBl_HWPwn8a5G2XQ, amqp_receivedExchange=amq.direct, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentType=application/json, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_deliveryTag=1}]
2016-02-18 16:04:51,147 - WARN - org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler [exec.testSpring-1] - Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:865)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:760)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1345)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1190)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7a5291d9.testSpring.inputChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
```

Comment: Confirm, please, that you have `@EnableIntegration` somewhere. From other side share more StackTrace on the matter. And that would be great if you will be able to minimize the config to let us to reproduce locally. Actually our `4.2.x` branch is fully based on the `SF-4.2.x` and we haven't met similar issue yet.

Comment: I do have `@EnableIntegration` elsewhere, but did try it here with no success. I have updated the issue with the stack trace, and will work on a minimized configuration for you.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I would like to see your `springIntegrationConfigHelper.createInboundChannelAdapter()`. I wonder if you do anything with the `phase` there...

Comment: I have added the `createInboundChannelAdapter()` code as well as a standalone config and test message class that duplicates the problem.

Comment: Share, please, the entire log since the application start. I would like to see how things are loaded by Spring

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your config isn't so simple to play from my side. I see that the problem comes from the AMQP Inbound Channel Adapter and looks like you have messages there in the queue before the application. I have similar config and messages in the `foo` queue prior starting the application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public static class MyConfig {

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "nullChannel")
    public String transform(String payload) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(payload);
        return payload;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel input() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost", AMQP.PROTOCOL.PORT);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
        container.setQueueNames("foo");
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter amqpInboundChannelAdapter() {
        AmqpInboundChannelAdapter channelAdapter = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(container());
        channelAdapter.setOutputChannel(input());
        return channelAdapter;
    }

}
```

And everything works well. The AMQP Inbound Channel Adapter has started after the `@Transformer` endpoint, therefore the last one is able to pick messages produced by the first after queue listening.

Would you mind to share DEBUG for the `org.springframework` category before that exception causes?

Comment: Regarding messages in the queue before the application starts, I tried both ways, ie messages in the queue before application startup and messages sent to the queue after startup. Please keep in mind that when I examine the log with SF 4.1.4 in place, I can see that the channel has a subscriber, but with SF 4.2.4 I observe that no subscriber is attached to the channel. I will compress my config more to match what you provided and will also get the DEBUG output for you.

Comment: OK. Share, please, the start point - how do you run the application?

Comment: It is run as a Java application: `public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextListener.getSpringContext();
  context.registerShutdownHook();
  context.refresh();
  context.start();
 }`   . However, it is interesting that you ask.  I run locally as an application in order to simplify my test setup.  In production it runs in a Tomcat 7 instance with a simple listener in the web.xml: `<listener-class>com.mimedia.index.config.ApplicationContextListener</listener-class>`.  My problems have been running as a java application.

Comment: What is `ApplicationContextListener`? Looks like we don't have such a class in Spring.

Comment: I looked, and it is using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. And here may be the source of the problem: there is some conditional registering of config classes with the context class loading based on environment variables.  Because things worked on 4.1.4 and not on 4.2.4, I did not consider anything bad would be happening here. I will explicitly test registering the config class in question and let you know.

Comment: I explicitly registered the CompressedConfig.class with the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext with no change in behavior, and I added the DEBUG output prior to the exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103906/discussion-between-jeff-m-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Here is my latest status: I constructed a standalone project and used the CompressedConfiguration that failed in the project that prompted my issue in the first place.  In my standalone project, things work when I switch from SF 4.1.4 to SF 4.2.4.  So now I have to determine how I am going to locate and isolate this problem.

Comment: I wanted to get back to you on this.  Unfortunately, I am being moved to a different project and this task was de-prioritized in favor of other things that I need to complete before transitioning.